# The elementary question on sign of Rational numbers

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

The image below can be used to show that $+\frac{8}{3}=\frac{+8}{3}$.

[image: +(8/3) = (+8)/3e]

Similarly we can show $-\frac{8}{3}=\frac{-8}{3}$. Now how can we show that 
$$-\dfrac{8}{3}=\dfrac{8}{-3}?$$

Comment: Expand the fraction by $-1$. How would you otherwise make sense of the concept of negative denominators?

Comment: How? please explain more for me

Comment: Moving leftwards by $\frac{8}{3}$ units is the same as moving rightwards by $8$ units, reflecting the path about $0$ and cutting up the path into $3$ equal parts.

Comment: Could you please *carefully* describe how the image shows that $+(8/3) = (+8)/3$. Also, what would the picture for $-(8/3) = (-8)/3$ look like? How you  answer these questions is pertinent to how we should show that $-(8/3) = 8/(-3)$.

Answer (score -2):

Note that:

$$\frac{8}{-3}=1\cdot \frac{8}{-3}=\frac{-1}{-1}\cdot \frac{8}{-3}=\frac{-8}{3}$$

Comment: I want an elementary proof for middle school. Here The student dont know the multiplication Rules yet.

Comment: We dont let use of multiplication.otherwise we can to say $\dfrac{8}{-3}=8\div(-3)=-(8\div 3)=-\dfrac{8}{3}$